# TOMCAT status 404 tried it all error

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat, http-status-code-404

im trying to run web.xml file and set server / server-mapping in it on tomcat. apparently the error log doesn't seem to have an error (if im not wrong) and I tried running it several times with  localhost:8080/Example03/servlet1 , localhost:8080/Example03 and 
localhost:8080/servlet1 as i read some articles posted the new implementations on certain versions of tomcat.. only shows http error 404(status report - requested resource not available). Using v6.0.. does anyone know something I could try to make it work

```
Jan 08, 2014 5:59:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;.
Jan 08, 2014 5:59:48 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Example03' did not find a matching property.
Jan 08, 2014 5:59:48 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 08, 2014 5:59:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 494 ms
Jan 08, 2014 5:59:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 08, 2014 5:59:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
Jan 08, 2014 5:59:48 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 08, 2014 5:59:48 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Jan 08, 2014 5:59:48 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/32  config=null
Jan 08, 2014 5:59:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 272 ms
```

web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.test.webapp.ServletExample</servlet-class>       
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/servlet1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<display-name>Example03</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

re-logged:

```
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;.
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:41 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Example03' did not find a matching property.
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:41 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 498 ms
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:42 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:42 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:42 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/23  config=null
Jan 08, 2014 7:25:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 646 ms
```

class:

```
package org.test.webapp;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet {



public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws ServletException,IOException{

    String name = req.getParameter("userName");
    String email = req.getParameter("email");
    String IP = req.getRemoteAddr();

    resp.getWriter().println("<html>");
    resp.getWriter().println("<head>");
    resp.getWriter().println("<title>this is the response</title>");
    resp.getWriter().println("</head>");
    resp.getWriter().println("<body>");

    resp.getWriter().println("your name is: "+ name);
    resp.getWriter().println("your email is: "+ email);
    resp.getWriter().println("your ip is: "+ IP);

    resp.getWriter().println("</body>"); 
    resp.getWriter().println("</html>");
}
}
```

index.html in WEB-INF:

```
<html>

<head>
<title> Test Form</title>
</head>


<body>
<form action="servlet1" method="get">
Name : <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Email : <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type = "submit" value="submit!">
</form>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: You are deploying any application? If your deploying any application post the `web.xml` of the application.

Comment: yes, just added web.xml.. it is suppose to show username and password entry at the screen. also have a .html file in WebContent

Comment: Do you have any file default.* or index.* in your Example03 folder?

Comment: no there isn't. cant find any in the folders either..

Comment: Your logs don't show the application being deployed at all. How are you deploying it ?

Comment: I reposted another log which shows all applications deployed

Comment: I still don't see your application being deployed. Only the default directories of tomcat are being deployed. How are you deploying it ?

Comment: I just started tomcat like 3 days ago.. so when you say deployed, does that mean you wanna look at my class file or .html file?

Comment: No no , by deployed I mean that how do you place your application inside tomcats directory so that tomcat can deploy it on startup ?

Comment: I downloaded tomcat thru the auto update feature of windows>preference>server.. with helios. my program auto configured it. unless theres a way of locating it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, I would suggest you start with tomcat from the scratch. Take a look into this [link](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/web-applications.html) .

Just to give a brief overview of how tomcat works

1. Download tomcat from the [official website](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) ( the one eclipse downloaded will also work fine but this way you will get to know the ins and outs of tomcat
2. Unzip it in a directory where you have read/write privileges
3. For a test run, goto `$Tomcat_Dir$/bin` and execute `startup.sh` or `startup.bat` ( in case of windows based systems)
4. In the browser, `localhost:8080` shoul give you the default page of tomcat
5. Next, package your application as a war ( e.g like myApp.war )
6. Place this `myApp.war` inside `$Tomcat_Dir$/webapps` folder and re-start tomcat. You will see a folder created inside the webapps folder with the same name as the war
7. Now `http://localhost:8080/myApp` will open the default page of your application ( if you have configured it). Otherwise, as per your web.xml, `localhost:8080/myApp/servlet1` will fire the servlet

Comment: hehe yea no prob.. one last question.. do I need to download both core and deployer for running web apps?

Comment: You just require the `Core` for everything